# Trying to get div dimensions in vh/vw instead of pixels

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to have resizable divs in my app. To do so I have to persist the changes that the user specified in my database.

My question is how do I change the units given to me from px to something else? When I do:

```
console.log(event.target.style.width)
```

it shows me the width in `px`. Is there any way to get it in, say, `%` or `vh`/`vw`?

Comment: it  depends on viewport, so u can do it only with js.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
event.target.style.width / document.documentElement.clientWidth * 100
```

Divide the width in pixels by the total viewport width, then multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that % can be for any parent. May not be worth mentioning, because it seems to be implied, but if you wanted to do it for any parent, you could change document.documentElement.clientWidth to document.getElementBy...("...")[...].style.width, if I understand document.documentElement.clientWidth to get the width of the viewport.